# check if user adds new image the form

Tags: php

I need to create else action. If user don't upload new image, in database should stay the old image. The code that adds image is:

```
<?php 
require_once 'database.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
$content_pic = false;
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = trim($_POST['title']);
$text = trim($_POST['text']);

if (!empty($_FILES["content_pic"])) {
        if ($_FILES["content_pic"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $uploads_dir = __DIR__ . '/files';
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["content_pic"]["tmp_name"];
            $name = $_FILES["content_pic"]["name"];
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "{$uploads_dir}/{$name}")) {
                $content_pic = "files/{$name}";
            }
        }
    }else{    
    }    

$db = database_connect();
$stmt = $db->prepare($select_query);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE content SET title = ?, text= ?, content_pic = ? WHERE id = ? ");       

header("Location: item_view.php?id=" . $id);
exit();
```

I don't know how create else action

Comment: And the db code isn't relevant you think?

Comment: added code that updates content table

Comment: It's rather simpler than you think. If empty don't query or don't use it in the query. Else, run the query as intended. You could also probably use a CASE.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You could try along these lines - where the variable `$content_pic` is set as false by default so if no image is uploaded a differnt sql statement can be executed.

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['text'] ) ){

        require_once 'database.php';
        require_once 'functions.php';


        $id     =   $_POST['id'];
        $title  =   trim( $_POST['title'] );
        $text   =   trim( $_POST['text'] );
        $field  =   'content_pic';


        /* will be populated if new upload detected */
        $content_pic = false;



        if( !empty( $_FILES[ $field ] ) ) {

            $file=$_FILES[ $field ];

            if( $file["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {

                $uploads_dir    = __DIR__ . '/files';
                $tmp_name       = $file['tmp_name'];
                $name           = $file['name'];
                $savepath       = $uploads_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;



                if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $savepath ) ) {
                    $content_pic = realpath( $savepath ) ? "files/{$name}" : false;
                }
            }
        }


        switch( $content_pic ){
            case false:
                $sql='update `content` set `title`=? `text`=? where `id`=?';
                $params=array( $title, $text, $id );
            break;
            default:
                $sql='update `content` set `title`=? `text`=?, `content_pic`=? where `id`=?';
                $params=array( $title, $text, $content_pic, $id );
            break;
        }

        $db = database_connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->execute( $params );
        $db->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: it didn't update picture if I want to load new picture. I added full code of that file

Comment: `didn't update picture` - do you mean in the database?

Comment: update. yes in database. If I choose new picture it didn't update it

Comment: the picture uploads ok and is saved in the designated location correctly? If you are still using `$stmt = $db->prepare( $select_query );` prior to trying to update the db it might be worth adding `$stmt->free_result()` ( or the PDO equivalent - $stmt->closeCursor() ) ) afterwards before you prepare and execute the `update` statement

Comment: The picture upload if I used code that I posted previously. Do I need to replace my code with yours or just add your switch statement?

Comment: The portion of code that actually handles the upload and then moves the file is virtually the same as yours so I can't understand why it no longer works. I incorporated various other portions of your code into the revised version

Comment: I have now tested the above - with minor modifications to suit my environment. The processing of the image upload works fine - the image is uploaded and stored in the location I specified and printing out a debug version of the sql looks correct. Please explain where the above fails for you - does the image upload? Does the sql statement fail?